# Was Christianity always the #1 religion since it started, or were there others?

Tags: religious-history

Christianity seems like it was a huge success in spreading. I have looked around in the old and new testament, (a small hint there) and I have done some research in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_of_Christianity), but barely anything.

Comment: What research have you already done into this? How are you measuring "#1 religion"?

Comment: oh, I forgot. New, sorry. I have looked around in the old and new testament, (a small hint there) and I have done some research in Wikipedia, but barely anything. here is the like to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_of_Christianity

Comment: Again, thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: /Is this better

Comment: Hi @YEETINGYEET, you're new here. In order to prove religious claims, you need a bit more than the bible. Wikipedia is okay, just don't cherry-pick.

Comment: This question is founded on a set of false premises.  This question needs to address the [Diocletian persecutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diocletianic_Persecution) (and others) as well as the wide variety of early Christian sects. This is [post hoc ergo prompter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc).  There is no evidence that Christianity grew without rival or was successful since inception.

Comment: Assume you mean only in Europe, where a minority of humans live.....

Comment: Wait, when did Christianity become the #1 religion? As measured by what? The OP's personal worldview?

Comment: Every religion starts with one adherent. The simple fact that there were other religions out there with organisations behind them (and thus implicitly multiple adherents) is all the proof you need to show that Christianity wasn't always the largest religion (if it ever was, but that's a different question).

Comment: @CareyGregory define #1 religion for a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christianity wasn't really the largest world religion, in either adherents or land area culturally dominated, until fairly recently.

For land area, the best way to visualize this is probably [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvFl6UBZLv4). Here's a screencap from the Early Middle ages:

[image]

What you should see there is that Christianity was fairly minor until it managed to covert most of Europe, which took until roughly the start of the late middle ages, and then it really took off after the "Age of Discovery" (early modern era).

For number of (perhaps nominal) devotees, the best thing to look at would be one of those new animated bar graphs. Unfortunately, I was only [able to find one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-icxn8asI8) that goes back into the ancient era, and I'm not sure its trustworthy<sup>*</sup>. However, it at least does the job of showing that Christianity was an also-ran around the time of the fall of the Roman Empire, and didn't take the lead until at least the late middle ages.

---

<sup>* - It claims to have done "my own research" with no references, and actually misspelled "Christian" on the graph.</sup>

Comment: I'm mainly including the bargraph link in the hopes that hopes that Cunningham's Law will bail us out here.

Comment: The "Islam" map is more than a little misleading.  The area in the middle of the Arabian Peninsula is called the [Empty Quarter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rub'_al_Khali) for a very good reason.

Comment: Another problem with this, or really any measurement of religion, is how to separate the actual believers from the cultural members, who pay lip service to the local religion because they fear the consequences of not doing so.  E.g. Christianity in most of Europe from the time it became dominant in a particular locality, until the Enlightenment.  (Late 17th-early 19th centuries.)

Comment: @Mark - Perhaps, but I'm using those maps for land area anyway. Population would be the animated bar graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about [Mythraism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithraism)? It was a very close competitor of Christianity. So much so, Christianity copied from it. The [halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(religious_iconography)) behind saints was originally Mythraist, not Christian. Many Christian customs and rituals are remarkably close: the sacrificial meal and nativity story, for example. Mythraism is much older than Christianity, so it's far more likely Christians copied Mythras than the other way around.

The [Isis religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isis#In_the_Greco-Roman_world) was also very popular. That's where the Virgin Mary comes from.

Christianity wasn't immediately very popular from the outset, and certainly not in the entire empire. Christianity spread slowly through the Eastern Empire, and more slowly in the West. It took at least a full century before it became noticeable, and another century to gain prominence.

Contrast that with the spread of islam. Mohammed and his followers gained more adherents during his life and the following 50 years than Christianity in three centuries.

Comment: Christianity is indeed a reinterpretation of pre-Christian beliefs; however, a reinterpretation, and it end-result, are not the same as that which is being reinterpreted; otherwise, there would have been no need for a new interpretation in the first place.

Comment: @Lucian: Yeah, it's absolutely amazing how many converts you can get when you have an army behind you.

Comment: There are also some parts of the world in which Christianity was somewhat significant but later disappeared, e.g. China and what is now Mongolia, both of which had Nestorian communities pre-13th century. Or Japan in the 16th century. In Japan the disappearance of Christianity was the result of decades of brutal oppression, but in the first two cases (I think) not.

Comment: @jamesqf: Agreed, but it seems you mistook my comment for the last paragraph of Jos' answer.